# Include d3d11 to code block

Tags: c++, windows, directx, codeblocks

I'm still new to c++ and directX , what I'm trying to do is to include d3d11 to my project , after some research I ended up finding that I need to download windowsSDK 8.1 and then I go to Settings -> Compiler -> Search directories , and Add directories to the compiler and the linker

but when I installed the sdk I couldn't find :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\lib

or :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\8.1\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\8.1\lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\8.1\bin

in the :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits
there is only folder ( 10 )

and in the :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\
there is only folder call ( bin )

I dont know if I'm doing something wrong or Microsoft change the directories or something .

Answer (score 2):

Generally you select which Windows SDK to use by editing the Visual C++ project properties and setting the General -> "Windows SDK Version" property.

If you are using some makefile-based build solution, the paths you want to use are actually:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86
-or-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64
```

Or if using the Windows 10 SDK (which does in fact support Win32 desktop applications targeting Windows Vista SP2 or later) and assuming you have the latest [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (16299)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/10/11/windows-10-fall-creators-update-sdk/) installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\winrt

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x86
-or-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x64
```

> As you are new to Direct3D, I'd recommend using the [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) with VS 2013, VS 2015, or VS 2017. Also see [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: thanks for the help and thanks for the learning materials .I'm using C::B so there is no windows sdk in the project settings , so how do I link these paths  which one is the Compiler and which one is the linker ?

Comment: Do you mean C#?

Comment: I mean I use Code Blocks IDE , and I can't find the windows sdk in the project settings , but I can link the compiler and linker manually